# How to make geckdriver not stop the Marionette listener when the session is closed?

Tags: python, asynchronous, webdriver, geckodriver, firefox-marionette

thanks in advance for take a time to help me. I'm working on a Python [library](https://github.com/douglasdcm/caqui) that runs asynchronous REST requests to WebDrivers and one issue I have is that when I close the GeckoDriver (Firefox) session, following the [W3 Webdriver documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-delete-session), the WebDriver stops listening Marionette, freezes for a while and starts listening Marionette on a new port. I've been using GeckoDriver and ChromeDriver both in version 113 to test the library, and for ChromeDriver it does not happens. The tests run smoothly and fast.

Here is what I do to reproduce the issue:

1. I open one terminal (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04) and start GeckoDriver on port 9999 `./geckodriver --port=9999`
2. In a new terminal I execute one of my test cases with `python -m pytest` that opens a session in WebDriver, do some stuff and closes it. Here is the code.

```
from pytest import fixture, mark
from caqui import asynchronous, synchronous  # this is from my library. Install with 'pip install caqui'
from tests.constants import PAGE_URL  # it is a local html, like '/html/playground.html'

@fixture
def __setup():
    driver_url = "http://127.0.0.1:9999"  # this is the URL to Geckodriver I started previously
    capabilities = {
        "desiredCapabilities": {
            "name": "webdriver",
            "browserName": "firefox",
            "marionette": True,
            "acceptInsecureCerts": True,
        }
    }
    session = synchronous.get_session(driver_url, capabilities)
    synchronous.go_to_page(
        driver_url,
        session,
        PAGE_URL,
    )
    yield driver_url, session
    synchronous.close_session(driver_url, session)

@mark.asyncio
async def test_click(__setup):
    driver_url, session = __setup
    locator_type = "xpath"
    locator_value = "//button"

    element = synchronous.find_element(driver_url, session, locator_type, locator_value)

    assert await asynchronous.click(driver_url, session, element) is True
```

3. When I go to the terminal where GeckoDriver is running, I can see this error. I tried to search for a solution, but I couldn't find anything that helps me. I appreciate any tip to fix it.

```
/home/douglas/web_drivers/geckodriver --port=9999
1686532134932   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
1686532158285   webdriver::command  WARN    You are using deprecated legacy session negotiation patterns (desiredCapabilities/requiredCapabilities), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Capabilities#Legacy
1686532158331   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: MOZ_CRASHREPORTER="1" MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_NO_REPORT="1" MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_SHUTDOWN="1" MOZ_NO_REMOTE="1" "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileShCnaZ"
console.warn: services.settings: Ignoring preference override of remote settings server
console.warn: services.settings: Allow by setting MOZ_REMOTE_SETTINGS_DEVTOOLS=1 in the environment
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
1686532161311   Marionette  INFO    Marionette enabled
1686532161371   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 44469
Read port: 44469
1686532161681   RemoteAgent WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
console.error: ({})
[ERROR glean_core] Error setting metrics feature config: Json(Error("EOF while parsing a value", line: 1, column: 0))
console.error: (new TypeError("linkMap is undefined", "resource://gre/modules/NewTabUtils.sys.mjs", 2019))
1686532167911   Marionette  INFO    Stopped listening on port 44469
[Child 11494, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox-J2eTmk/firefox-113.0.2+build1/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
[Child 11494, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox-J2eTmk/firefox-113.0.2+build1/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
[Child 11494, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox-J2eTmk/firefox-113.0.2+build1/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
[Child 11494, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox-J2eTmk/firefox-113.0.2+build1/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
[Child 11494, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox-J2eTmk/firefox-113.0.2+build1/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
[Child 11494, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox-J2eTmk/firefox-113.0.2+build1/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
[Child 11494, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox-J2eTmk/firefox-113.0.2+build1/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
[Child 11494, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (Conduits, ConduitClosed) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox-J2eTmk/firefox-113.0.2+build1/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/Prompter.sys.mjs, line 1042: DataCloneError: The object could not be cloned.
[Child 11620, Main Thread] WARNING: JSWindowActorChild::SendRawMessage (MarionetteCommands, MarionetteCommandsParent:clickElement) not sent: !CanSend() || !mManager || !mManager->CanSend(): file /build/firefox-J2eTmk/firefox-113.0.2+build1/dom/ipc/jsactor/JSWindowActorChild.cpp:57
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/Prompter.sys.mjs, line 1042: AbortError: Actor 'Prompt' destroyed before query 'Prompt:Open' was resolved
console.error: "Failed to import bookmarks from chrome://browser/content/default-bookmarks.html: Error: places.sqlite#0: cannot execute operation GuidHelper.getItemId, the connection is already closing"
console.error: "Bookmarks.html file could be corrupt. " (new Error("places.sqlite#0: cannot execute operation GuidHelper.getItemId, the connection is already closing", "resource://gre/modules/Sqlite.sys.mjs", 502))
console.log: "RemoteSettingsWorker error: Error: Can't import when we've started shutting down."
console.error: (new RemoteSettingsWorkerError("Error: Can't import when we've started shutting down.", "resource://services-settings/RemoteSettingsWorker.sys.mjs", 39))
console.log: "RemoteSettingsWorker error: Error: Can't import when we've started shutting down."
console.error: (new RemoteSettingsWorkerError("Error: Can't import when we've started shutting down.", "resource://services-settings/RemoteSettingsWorker.sys.mjs", 39))
console.log: "RemoteSettingsWorker error: Error: Can't import when we've started shutting down."
console.error: (new RemoteSettingsWorkerError("Error: Can't import when we've started shutting down.", "resource://services-settings/RemoteSettingsWorker.sys.mjs", 39))
console.log: "RemoteSettingsWorker error: Error: Can't import when we've started shutting down."
console.log: "RemoteSettingsWorker error: Error: Can't import when we've started shutting down."
console.error: (new RemoteSettingsWorkerError("Error: Can't import when we've started shutting down.", "resource://services-settings/RemoteSettingsWorker.sys.mjs", 39))
console.error: (new RemoteSettingsWorkerError("Error: Can't import when we've started shutting down.", "resource://services-settings/RemoteSettingsWorker.sys.mjs", 39))
console.error: (new Error("IndexedDB: main/doh-config getLastModified() IndexedDB:  execute() The application is shutting down", "resource://services-settings/IDBHelpers.jsm", 18))
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs, line 727: Error: Phase "profile-before-change" is finished, it is too late to register completion condition "DoHController: clear state and remove observers"
WARNING: A blocker encountered an error while we were waiting.
          Blocker:  Waiting for ping task
          Phase: TelemetryController: Waiting for pending ping activity
          State: (none)
WARNING: Error: Phase "profile-before-change" is finished, it is too late to register completion condition "OS.File: flush I/O queued before profileBeforeChange"
WARNING: addBlocker@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:727:15
addBlocker@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:523:26
addBlocker@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:458:15
setupShutdown@resource://gre/modules/osfile/osfile_async_front.jsm:1548:28
@resource://gre/modules/osfile/osfile_async_front.jsm:1568:16
@resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm:12:30
@resource://gre/modules/TelemetryStorage.sys.mjs:10:28
_checkPendingPings@resource://gre/modules/TelemetrySend.sys.mjs:859:17
setup@resource://gre/modules/TelemetrySend.sys.mjs:799:18
setup@resource://gre/modules/TelemetrySend.sys.mjs:237:30
setupTelemetry/this._delayedInitTask<@resource://gre/modules/TelemetryControllerParent.sys.mjs:824:36
observe@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:576:16

console.error: "TelemetryScheduler.shutdown - Already shut down"
WARNING: A blocker encountered an error while we were waiting.
          Blocker:  Waiting for ping task
          Phase: TelemetryController: Waiting for pending ping activity
          State: (none)
WARNING: Error: Phase "profile-before-change" is finished, it is too late to register completion condition "OS.File: flush I/O queued before profileBeforeChange"
WARNING: addBlocker@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:727:15
addBlocker@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:523:26
addBlocker@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:458:15
setupShutdown@resource://gre/modules/osfile/osfile_async_front.jsm:1548:28
@resource://gre/modules/osfile/osfile_async_front.jsm:1568:16
@resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm:12:30
@resource://gre/modules/TelemetryStorage.sys.mjs:10:28
_checkPendingPings@resource://gre/modules/TelemetrySend.sys.mjs:859:17
setup@resource://gre/modules/TelemetrySend.sys.mjs:799:18
setup@resource://gre/modules/TelemetrySend.sys.mjs:237:30
setupTelemetry/this._delayedInitTask<@resource://gre/modules/TelemetryControllerParent.sys.mjs:824:36
observe@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:576:16

WARNING: A blocker encountered an error while we were waiting.
          Blocker:  Waiting for ping task
          Phase: TelemetryController: Waiting for pending ping activity
          State: (none)
WARNING: Error: Phase "profile-before-change" is finished, it is too late to register completion condition "OS.File: flush I/O queued before profileBeforeChange"
WARNING: addBlocker@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:727:15
addBlocker@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:523:26
addBlocker@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:458:15
setupShutdown@resource://gre/modules/osfile/osfile_async_front.jsm:1548:28
@resource://gre/modules/osfile/osfile_async_front.jsm:1568:16
@resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm:12:30
@resource://gre/modules/TelemetryStorage.sys.mjs:10:28
_checkPendingPings@resource://gre/modules/TelemetrySend.sys.mjs:859:17
setup@resource://gre/modules/TelemetrySend.sys.mjs:799:18
setup@resource://gre/modules/TelemetrySend.sys.mjs:237:30
setupTelemetry/this._delayedInitTask<@resource://gre/modules/TelemetryControllerParent.sys.mjs:824:36
observe@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:576:16

WARNING: A blocker encountered an error while we were waiting.
          Blocker:  TelemetryController: shutting down
          Phase: profile-before-change-telemetry
          State: Error getting state: Error: Phase "profile-before-change" is finished, it is too late to register completion condition "OS.File: flush I/O queued before profileBeforeChange" at addBlocker@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:727:15
addBlocker@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:523:26
addBlocker@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:458:15
setupShutdown@resource://gre/modules/osfile/osfile_async_front.jsm:1548:28
@resource://gre/modules/osfile/osfile_async_front.jsm:1568:16
@resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm:12:30
@resource://gre/modules/TelemetryStorage.sys.mjs:10:28
_checkPendingPings@resource://gre/modules/TelemetrySend.sys.mjs:859:17
setup@resource://gre/modules/TelemetrySend.sys.mjs:799:18
setup@resource://gre/modules/TelemetrySend.sys.mjs:237:30
setupTelemetry/this._delayedInitTask<@resource://gre/modules/TelemetryControllerParent.sys.mjs:824:36
observe@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:576:16

WARNING: Error: Phase "profile-before-change" is finished, it is too late to register completion condition "OS.File: flush I/O queued before profileBeforeChange"
WARNING: addBlocker@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:727:15
addBlocker@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:523:26
addBlocker@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:458:15
setupShutdown@resource://gre/modules/osfile/osfile_async_front.jsm:1548:28
@resource://gre/modules/osfile/osfile_async_front.jsm:1568:16
@resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm:12:30
@resource://gre/modules/TelemetryStorage.sys.mjs:10:28
_checkPendingPings@resource://gre/modules/TelemetrySend.sys.mjs:859:17
setup@resource://gre/modules/TelemetrySend.sys.mjs:799:18
setup@resource://gre/modules/TelemetrySend.sys.mjs:237:30
setupTelemetry/this._delayedInitTask<@resource://gre/modules/TelemetryControllerParent.sys.mjs:824:36
observe@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs:576:16

JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs, line 727: Error: Phase "profile-before-change" is finished, it is too late to register completion condition "OS.File: flush I/O queued before profileBeforeChange"
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs, line 727: Error: Phase "profile-before-change" is finished, it is too late to register completion condition "OS.File: flush I/O queued before profileBeforeChange"
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs, line 727: Error: Phase "profile-before-change" is finished, it is too late to register completion condition "OS.File: flush I/O queued before profileBeforeChange"
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs, line 727: Error: Phase "profile-before-change" is finished, it is too late to register completion condition "OS.File: flush I/O queued before profileBeforeChange"
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs, line 727: Error: Phase "profile-before-change" is finished, it is too late to register completion condition "OS.File: flush I/O queued before profileBeforeChange"
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.sys.mjs, line 727: Error: Phase "profile-before-change" is finished, it is too late to register completion condition "OS.File: flush I/O queued before profileBeforeChange"
console.error: (new Error("SessionFile is closed", "resource:///modules/sessionstore/SessionFile.sys.mjs", 370))
console.error: (new AbortError("IOUtils: Shutting down and refusing additional I/O tasks", (void 0), 890))
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/CrashManager.sys.mjs, line 927: AbortError: IOUtils: Shutting down and refusing additional I/O tasks
RunWatchdog: Mainthread nested event loops during hang: 
 --- (no nested event loop active)
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 11730
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
1686532237641   webdriver::command  WARN    You are using deprecated legacy session negotiation patterns (desiredCapabilities/requiredCapabilities), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Capabilities#Legacy
1686532237646   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: MOZ_CRASHREPORTER="1" MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_NO_REPORT="1" MOZ_CRASHREPORTER_SHUTDOWN="1" MOZ_NO_REMOTE="1" "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileSbneTZ"
console.warn: services.settings: Ignoring preference override of remote settings server
console.warn: services.settings: Allow by setting MOZ_REMOTE_SETTINGS_DEVTOOLS=1 in the environment
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
1686532240302   Marionette  INFO    Marionette enabled
1686532240309   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 36735
Read port: 36735
1686532240485   RemoteAgent WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
console.error: ({})
```